# JS timing events within infinite loop / interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I have looked around, tried several solutions and have not been able to find a solution :/

What I am looking to do is to have a loop that runs every second which contains events that are fired with different delays depending on the event type and conditions such event type pertains.

Tried self building the infinite loop and logic with while(true) and counters, as well as using setInterval and setTimeout, but all result into the same end result (result: see bottom of the question (based on code examples that use setInterval and setTimeout)).

This result is due to (or at least so I believe, would be nice if someone can confirm) a situation where my callstack contains new every second invocations of the whole loop and X amount of non processed eventY's that have been invoked -> the very first run the behavior is as expected, but after this the callstack begins to accumulate the non processed event Y's and prints them out every second or per the speed of the main loop.

some example code to explain (using setInterval and setTimeout):

```
function start() {
    setInterval(eventList, 1000);
};

function eventList() {
    console.log("foo")
    eventY();
};

async function eventY() {
    await newTimeout(0,5).then(() => {
        console.log("bar");
    })
};

function newTimeout (minutes, seconds) {
    let counter = (minutes*60+seconds)*1000;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, counter));   
}
```

OR more cumbersome and forceful delay (leads to unpredictable behavior at best and with longer events, the same end result):

```
function newTimeout(minutes, seconds) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let counter = minutes*60+seconds;
        let interval = setInterval((() => {
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve();
            }
        }), 1000)
    });
};
```

ALSO tried using just setTimeout to stay away from the setInterval as I understand it is liable to clutter your callstack, ofc the below doesn't change anything now looking at it, but thought I would put it in anyway as I tend to prefer the thought of setTimeout that the function calls itself creating the loop that way.

```
function start() {
    try {
        eventList();    
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    } finally {
        setTimeout(() => start(), 1000);
    }
};
```

end result is basically:

foo

foo

foo

foo

foo

bar

foo

bar

foo

bar

foo

Comment: confused by your use of "seconds" when `setTimeout()` takes delay parameter in milliseconds. In the `newTImeOut()` method the parameters are called `minutes` and `seconds` - which you calculate and send to `setTimeout()` - is your intent to time that out after 5ms or 5seconds?

Comment: Promises are only ever resolved once, it's not something you would use in a setInterval.

Comment: When you say, "a loop that runs every second which contains events that are fired with different delays" so you mean the loop really runs every second or runs with a gap of a second after the events have all fired. In other words can a new loop start before the inner events have finished?

Comment: Randy: oops forgot to put *1000 on the example, fixed now to: let counter = (minutes*60+seconds)*1000; -> won't make a difference re. the problem though.

Comment: Keith can you expand? This sounds like it is in the right tracks of answering the why this happens.

Comment: Mark, yes that is sought behavior that a new loop starts before all the inner events have finished. Basically the one event may need to run with 10min delay while some other event may need to run every second and another with 1min delay. For all events it applies that they should not be fired again until the event is complete, but at the same time the other events that have completed should be fired in the meantime.

Comment: Further to above, that is the reason why e.g. promise array and promise all won't work as it will then delay the faster events. One solution that allows the sought behavior is to use setTimeout for each event and make the event call itself once finished with for instance .then(), but this can't be the best solution (especially if the event needs to remember the state, also for the first start would have to start each event one by one)?